# Get attribute value for sub element based on sub element text in SVG (XML) file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, svg

I'm trying to get the value of a particular attribute of a sub-element in sub-elements of a particular value.
Sub-element = "text" and
Attribute = "transform"

I'm using XML.Linq. I looked at several tutorials including here: https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/353127-linq-by-example-5-linq-to-xml-querying/

The IEnumerable XElement try1, try2, and try3 in the code below all remain null.  The value that I'm trying to return is "matrix(0.19885 0 -0 0.19885 468.353 9352.33)"

Below is a sample XML and c# code:

XML in SVG file:

```
<svg viewBox="-4773 -7277 42423 24101" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-rule="evenodd" xml:space="preserve">
   <g clip-path="url(#clipId0)" fill="rgb(100,100,100)" stroke="rgb(100,100,100)" stroke-width="0">
      <text transform="matrix(0.19885 0 -0 0.19885 468.353 9352.33)" font-family="Verdana,'sans-serif'" font-size="1.37493">Test1 and other text</text>
      <text transform="matrix(0.19885 0 -0 0.19885 567.778 9352.33)" font-family="Verdana,'sans-serif'" font-size="1.37493">Test2 and other text</text>
   </g>
</svg>
```

c# code:

```
    public string GetAttributeValue()
    {

        XElement xml_Elem = XElement.Load(_FilePath);
        List<string> retVal = new List<string>;


        IEnumerable<XElement> try1 =
            from el in xml_Elem.Elements("g")
            where el.Element("text").Value.Contains("Test1")
            select el;

        foreach (XElement el in try1)
        {
            retVal.Add(el.Attribute("transform").ToString());
        }


        IEnumerable<XElement> try2 =
            from el in xml_Elem.Descendants("text")
            where el.Value.Contains("Test1")
            select el;

        foreach (XElement el in try2)
        {
            retVal.Add(el.Attribute("transform").ToString());
        }


        IEnumerable<XAttribute> try3 =
            from el in xml_Elem.Descendants("text")
            where el.Value.Contains("Test1")
            select el.Attribute("transforem");

        foreach (XAttribute at in try3)
        {
            retVal.Add(at.Value);
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

The problem was with the namespaces.  See duplicate post reference.

Comment: Your problem is the namespacing in your xml. See dup to get it right :)

Comment: You have left out a lot of the xml file and the element 'g' needs to be a descendant not an element.